# When is bounds and frame set for views/layers in Swift?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, swift

I have something like this in a `UIView` subclass:

```
override var bounds : CGRect {
  didSet {
    somelayer.frame = bounds
  }
}
```

In the corresponding `somelayer`, I have this:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
  didSet {
    someFunction()
  }
}
```

Now if the view is initialized using `super.init(frame: someFrame)`, the first block is not called. This appears to indicate that the `bounds` property is not set alongside `frame`.

If I change the first block to `override var frame`, then it will be called by `super.init(frame: someFrame)`, and it will set the `frame` of `somelayer`. Interestingly, when that happens, the second block is called, suggesting that `bounds` and `frame` are set at the same time (which is what I'd expect, too).

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_333) are not called during initialization.

> willSet and didSet observers are not called when a property is first
>   initialized. They are only called when the property’s value is set
>   outside of an initialization context.

Perhaps the way the view is being constructed internally, the frame is set post initialization but the bounds are not.

Then later, when setting the frame of the layer, the bounds are also updated by the internal method.

Comment: Thanks! I should have RTFM more carefully.

Comment: Using Swift 2 / iOS9 I am seeing willSet / didSet get called in an initialization context, in my case when subclassing UIView I'm seeing them get called from inside super.init(coder: aDecoder) in init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder). Actually I'm having the opposite problem where the observer on the `frame` property doesn't seem to be called **after** initialisation even though the value changes.

Comment: @JarrodSmith I'm facing the same - did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @swalkner no I ended up having to use a different approach.