# Property observers for UIView bounds and frame react differently

Tags: swift, uiview, properties, bounds, observers

While I am exploring the option to observe a `UIView`'s `bounds` or `frame` change (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000664/is-there-a-uiview-resize-event) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616418/how-to-detect-when-uiview-size-is-changed-in-swift-ios-xcode)), I have encountered a very strange discrepancy: **`didSet` and `willSet` will be triggered differently based on where you put your `UIView` in the view hierarchy**:

- If I use property observer for `UIView` at the **root of a view controller**, I will only get `didSet` and `willSet` events from `frame` changes.
- If I use property observer for `UIView` that is a **subview** inside a view controller, I will only get `didSet` and `willSet` events from `bounds` changes.

I’d like to note first that I’m explicitly avoiding KVO approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874288/how-can-i-do-key-value-observing-and-get-a-kvo-callback-on-a-uiviews-frame) since it’s not officially supported. I’m also not looking to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30616739/1452174) since that won’t work for observing changes of subviews (see the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews)). **This question assumes my preference to use `didSet` and `willSet` to observe a `UIView`’s `bounds` / `frame` changes.**

The closest question I have come across is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176543/when-is-bounds-and-frame-set-for-views-layers-in-swift) but it covers only the initialization phrase, and also doesn’t mention the case of observing a subview.

### Details

To see this in action, check out  [my sample project](https://github.com/pt2277/testViewBoundsChange).

I am really puzzled why `bounds` observers are sometimes not called, so I added `frame` observers as well, and even `frame` observers are sometimes not called. Eventually, I was able to find the key setting where they work differently: the view’s placement in view hierarchy, as described above.

How I test: in both cases, rotating the device to change the view’s `frame` / `bounds`.

Here’s my `UIView` subclass:

public class BoundsObservableView: UIView {

```
    public weak var boundsDelegate: ViewBoundsObserving?

    public override var bounds: CGRect {
        willSet {
            print("BOUNDS willSet bounds: \(bounds), frame: \(frame)")
            boundsDelegate?.boundsWillChange(self)
        }
        didSet {
            print("BOUNDS didSet bounds: \(bounds), frame: \(frame)")
            boundsDelegate?.boundsDidChange(self)
        }
    }

    public override var frame: CGRect {
        willSet {
            print("FRAME willSet frame: \(frame), bounds: \(bounds)")
            boundsDelegate?.boundsWillChange(self)
        }
        didSet {
            print("FRAME didSet frame: \(frame), bounds: \(bounds)")
            boundsDelegate?.boundsDidChange(self)
        }
    }
}
```

In my sample code, if you rotate the device, you will see that in one case where I’m observing the root view (`ViewController`’s `self.view` -- shown in blue), I would never get notified of `bounds` change, despite it having actually changed. The opposite goes for a subview -- I never got notified of `frame` change, despite it having changed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Environment

I'm testing this project on Xcode 9.3 with iOS 11.4 SDK on devices like iPad Air and iPad Pro. I have not tried in on iOS 12 beta.

### My Questions

- Why do `didSet` and `willSet` get triggered differently when `UIView` is placed differently in the view hierarchy?
- When `didSet` for `bounds` is triggered, why won’t `didSet` for `frame` triggered as well (for subviews)? Vice versa (for root view)?
- What is a way, if any, to ensure that I can always observe `bounds` change of a `UIView` no matter where I put it in the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my repost in [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/317152?et=watches.email.thread#317152), `QuinceyMorris` helped me clarifying issues with this approach as well as an approach that would work no matter where I put the view in the view hierarchy.

> ... an Obj-C property can change value without having its setter called. Changing the instance variable (of simple properties) is a very common Obj-C pattern. It is of course not KVO compliant without additional work, but that's why KVO compliance is not found universally.
>
> ... Your willSet/didSet accessors will only trigger when the change goes through their own property. There is nothing you can predict or assume about which property will be used. Even if you see a regularity now, there may be edge cases that are different, and the behavior may change in the future.

Based on his recommendation that I override `layoutSubviews`, here's my updated subclass (just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5003296/1452174)):

```
public protocol ViewBoundsObserving: class {
    // Notifies the delegate that view's `bounds` has changed.
    // Use `view.bounds` to access current bounds
    func boundsDidChange(_ view: BoundsObservableView, from previousBounds: CGRect);
}

/// You can observe bounds change with this view subclass via `ViewBoundsObserving` delegate.
public class BoundsObservableView: UIView {
    
    public weak var boundsDelegate: ViewBoundsObserving?
    
    private var previousBounds: CGRect = .zero
    
    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        if (bounds != previousBounds) {
            print("Bounds changed from \(previousBounds) to \(bounds)")
            boundsDelegate?.boundsDidChange(self, from: previousBounds)
            previousBounds = bounds
        }
        
        // UIView's implementation will layout subviews for me using Auto Resizing mask or Auto Layout constraints.
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```